# Runtime.exec an app packaged in same jar (in Win)?

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I'm very new to Java and am trying to achieve the following (please forgive my lack of knowledge with any proper or known etiquette that I've broken):

I've created a project, with 2 packages; **src.ext** and **src.utils**
* **src.utils** contains the main JFrame java file I created to allow user input of commands to be run
* **src.ext** contains the executables

What I want to be able to do is utilize Runtime.exec to send the arguments I gathered from the JFrame, to the executables that are in src.ext

As I understand it, Runtime.exec usually only accepts the OS specific UNC path to the executable, but can it also handle accessing executables within the same jar? How?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600146/run-exe-which-is-packaged-inside-jar may cover what you want, by extracting exe to a temporary file...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just call it by its name, since it is in the same location on the disk.  Like so

```
String[] params = {mySweetExecutable, arg1,arg2};
```

`Runtime.exec(params);`

Answer (score 0):

Here sample of my code:

package com.wenxiong.hiddenrecover;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Stack;

public class HiddenRecover {
static Stack<File> stack = new Stack<File>();
static String rootDir;
/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (args.length != 1) {
        System.out.println("Sample of usages:");
        System.out.println("Command: java com.wenxiong.hiddenrecover.HiddenRecover C:\\");
        System.out.println("Command: java com.wenxiong.hiddenrecover.HiddenRecover C:\\somedirectory");
    } else {

        rootDir = args[0];
        stack.push(new File(rootDir));

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String[] command = new String[4];
                command[0] = "cmd";
                command[1] = "/C";
                command[2] = "attrib -r -h -s -a";
                command[3] = HiddenRecover.rootDir;

                while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                    File currFile = stack.pop();
                    if (currFile.isDirectory()) {
                        File[] arr = currFile.listFiles();
                        for (File item : arr) {
                            stack.push(item);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Recovering: " + currFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    command[3] = currFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    try {
                        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        System.out.println("Could not recover: " + command[3] + " " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }       
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }


}


 }
```

Just modify based on your needs.