# Launch .app from inside Java project?

Tags: java, macos

I hava a .app application and I want to include it inside my project and launch it from inside a jar. Here is what I have so far:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[] { "open",  "SomeApp.app"} );`

`SomeApp.app` is placed in the root of the src folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to execute

```
open /path/to/some.app
```

and

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[] { "open", "/path/to/app/SomeApp.app"} );
```

now your app is in jar so it won't be a app file any more you need to have it on disk at `/path/to/app`

You need to extract `.app` file from `.jar` and then execute it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600146/run-exe-which-is-packaged-inside-jar) is how to do it