# In Warbler, how do I access compiled binaries through Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, jar, jruby, warbler

I have a piece of Ruby code which depends on a binary built from C. I generally call the binary through backticks. But now when I package the Ruby code into a jar using Warbler, I'm not sure on how I'd be able to access the binary.

My code structure looks like this:

```
root/  
  |--bin/
       |--exec.rb   #This is the executable when I call java -jar example.jar
  |--lib/
       |--Module1.rb #This dir contains all the ruby modules my code requires
  |--ext/
       |--a.out     #A binary compiled with gcc
  |--.gemspec       #A file to guide warbler into building this structure into a jar
```

I used `warble` to build this entire structure into a jar. In Ruby, I can access my `a.out` through the following statement in exec.rb.

```
exec = "#{File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__)), 'ext'))}/a.out}"; 
`exec`
```

But when I try this code packaged as a jar I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: file:/path/to/my/jar/example.jar!/root/ext/a.out: not found
```

So, how do I access the executable packaged in a jar.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `jar` in the `lib` folder.

Require it in the code

```
require 'java'
Dir["#{File.expand_path(File.join(Rails.root, 'lib'))}/\*.jar"].each { |jar| require jar } 
# A war is treated as a directory.  If that is not successful add the lib folder to the CLASSPATH environment variable
```

Then it should be available to be used.

**Edit:**

Maybe this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/600198/643500 you can implement it with JRuby.

Comment: I had tried something similar, but it didn't work. I think my question was ambiguous so I've rephrased my question with more background to what I've done.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll try to give it a shot.