# How to call Python script from a Java JAR file

Tags: java, python, jar, runtime, jython

Currently I'm working on a simulation project that involve both Java and Python.

The simulator interface is written in Java Swing. The solver/engine is written in Python.

I'm using Eclipse to develop the project. I use Process and Runtime to call the Python Script with some parameters. I use pydev inside Eclipse to run the Python script.

Now, after I export the project to a JAR file, the Python code is located inside the JAR as a folder. Apparently, java won't be able to call the Python Script in the JVM anymore. Is there a way to use JAR to call Python Script and parse the simulation results?

Jython might be a option, but I'm trying to see if there is simpler way without change significant amount of code from the original Python script.

Thank you so much, 
William

Comment: OP have you solved it at the end? I'm in the same trouble. I figured it out that when exported and launched the jar, the directory the process ('python script.py') is directly above the jar and cannot access the scripts inside it, but cannot go further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Part1**:(**import** .jar file as library in Eclipse)

You make a new project to Eclipse(name:Project1)
 When you *open* it you see **JRE System Library[java version something]**

**1**.**right click** on *JRE System Library*

**2**.Go->*Build Path*->*Configure Build Path*

**3**.You can see (***Up right Corner*** the button[***add jars*** or **add** **external *jars***]

*Here i advise you to choose the **first(add jars)** but..

*First **copy**(or move) the **Python.jar** inside the     project((example):Project 1)

*Now you can add it with the button(**add jars**).

***In this way when you finish your project the Python.jar will be
 imported inside the project(If you export it as a .jar from Eclipse)**

..Now you can call any method of **Python.jar** just(import it into the class
you want to use and call it)

Let me know if that works for you...

***Part 2:***

- Running a file which **is inside the eclipse Project**(warning! before export it to jar):

1.Way(**Following the path of file**)

```
 try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:/NameOfEclipseProject/Project/src/pack(Package)/script.py");

    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

2.i will add them soon..(it has been time since i used them try to find)

- Running the script **after export project to jar**(warning! after export to jar)

Check this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600146/run-exe-which-is-packaged-inside-jar)

Comment: Hello crAlex, thanks for the answer, I understand how to add jar and access methods in the jar. My question here is I have package a python file in the jar, say print hello world, it's not part of the jython.jar. Through command line I can do this "java -jar jython.jar print.py" and it will call the python. Now I want to know how to do this in Eclipse...Thank you :)

Comment: hm.. i thought you wanted to access a method from jar file...(if i know something more i will give  try)(my answer was out then.....)

Comment: I have done something similar before(but with an exe into the jar) one solution is to use java to copy the script somewhere(out of the jar) and then call it with (Runtime).If you dont know how to do this(copy and call from inside the jar) add a comment and i will add an extra part to the answer before

Comment: Hello crAlex, by copy and put the file into the jar will hide the implementation of the python script (or at least another level of security), so it is the preferred method. It would be really appreciate if you can let me know how you called the exe from the jar inside Eclipse. Thank you!

Comment: I haven't got it working yet, but I'm trying your second method in Part 2. try to extract it run it and delete when the Java program quits.

Answer (score 1):

Python must be configured in system path:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python script.py");
```

Or this:

```
ScriptEngine python = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("python");
python.eval(stringHere); # script engine runs code
```

Comment: Funny story. I've spent hours on Stackoverflow trying to explain path configuration and pip setup.

Comment: Hello Malik, thanks for the explanation. Yet, it didn't really answered my question. I did use Process p as you suggested in method one, it did work when I run through IDE (such as Eclipse). HOWEVER, when I export the whole project to a runnable JAR, the python folder and it's scripts can not be called with the normal system directory because it's in a ZIP (JAR) file. I'm trying to figure out how I would be able to call it from the JAR.

Comment: I know you're trying to avoid it, but I'd go with Jython. Just import Jython.jar into Eclipse, and you're good to go.

Comment: Just a quick question to you, Malik. Let's say I package a __run__.py or main.py inside the JAR and import that in to Eclipse, do you know how can call the __run__.py file? In command line you can do a java -jar, but in Eclipse how to call that file? Thanks a lot!