# Starting the exe from the package - JAVA

Tags: java, package

Is possible put `exe` file into the java package and run this `exe` file by java program?

Comment: Yes, include it in your jar file and extract it at runtime (keywords: `getResourceAsStream`, `FileOutputStream`).

Comment: I have to unzip the file? Or it can be run directly from the package?

Comment: As I said, you need to extract ("unzip") the exe in order to run it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [run exe which is packaged inside jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600146/run-exe-which-is-packaged-inside-jar)